# Preprocessor definitions not working in C

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I've been frantically trying to get this following code to work. The preprocessor definitions WIDR and LIDR aren't working and it's giving me the compile error:

```
projects/elcain.c: In function ‘main’:
projects/elcain.c:17:6: error: ‘WIDR’ undeclared (first use in this function)
 if ( WIDR ) {
      ^
projects/elcain.c:17:6: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
projects/elcain.c:19:13: error: ‘LIDR’ undeclared (first use in this function)
 } else if ( LIDR ) {
```

I don't really have experience with preprocessor macros, or the preprocessor in general, so go easy on me.

Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#ifdef _WIN32
#define WIDR 1
#elif defined _linux_
#define LIDR 1
#endif

int main () {

char* directory = (char*) malloc (1);
if ( WIDR ) {
    strcpy(directory, "C:\\TEMP\\");
} else if ( LIDR ) {
    strcpy(directory, "~/.temp/");
} else {
    *directory = 0x00;
}

printf("%s\n", directory);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Neither `_WIN32` nor `_linux_` are defined.

Comment: If `_WIN32` is not defined then `WIDR` istn't defined either. Anywa, this is completely wrong, because `WIRD` and `LIDR` cannot be defined both, but they are both used in the program.

Comment: BTW `(char*) malloc (1);` is absurd. Think about it.

Comment: You should probably explain what exactly you are trying to achieve. This sounds like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: I program in C++ and decided to try a bit of C. When i saw that "new" is a C++ keyword i got shocked and started looking for a substitute. Thanks for the advice though, and I hope you don't mind me asking, what should I use instead of that malloc code?

Comment: @UtkuBoduroglu please read my previous comment. And look at the answers below.

Comment: I was just going to write something, but when I got with the preprocessor stuff, it kinda turned into this.

Comment: @UtkuBoduroglu learn the basics of the C language before fiddling around with `malloc` and preprocessor stuff.

Comment: Note that Windows has a built-in API function which will hand you the designated temp directory on a silver plate: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364992(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is something like this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

#if defined unix        ||                                                     \
    defined __unix      ||                                                     \
    defined __unix__    ||                                                     \
    defined __linux__   ||                                                     \
    defined __FreeBSD__ ||                                                     \
    defined __CYGWIN__  ||                                                     \
    (defined __APPLE__ && defined __MACH__)
    static const char TMP_DIR[] = "~/.temp/";
#elif defined WIN32   ||                                                       \
      defined _WIN32  ||                                                       \
      defined __WIN32
    static const char TMP_DIR[] = "C:\\TEMP\\";
#else
    #error "Platform not supported"
#endif

int
main(void)
{
    printf("%s\n", TMP_DIR);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Other way around, yeah? If defined windows -> `"C:\\TEMP\\"`.

Comment: my bad, yeah, 'was bit in a hurry :)

Answer (score 3):

You probably simply want this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


int main () {
#ifdef _WIN32
   char directory[] = "C:\\TEMP\\";
#elif defined _linux_
   char directory[] = "~/.temp/";
#else
#error Neither _WIN32 nor _linux_ are defined
#endif

   printf("%s\n", directory);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think the third case in your conditional should be `#else` instead of `#elif`!

Comment: Thanks for the help! Will look into more C before trying stuff like this. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

In fact both WIDR and LIDR are conditional compilation directives. In other words they exist at compilation time only.

Change your code like this:

```
#ifdef WIDR 
    strcpy(directory, "C:\\TEMP\\");
#elif defined LDIR
    strcpy(directory, "~/.temp/");
#else
    *directory = 0x00;
#endif
```

then compilation errors will gone